# What does @<(cat <<- EOF do in Bash?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, heredoc, process-substitution

I've stumbled upon some weird heredoc usage in a Bash script. A simplified example goes like this:

```
do_stuff() {
      notify @<(cat <<- EOF
  {
      "key": "value",
       <more JSON data>
  }
  EOF
               )
  }
```

What does the `@<(cat <<- EOF` part do? How is it different from a regular heredoc?

Comment: `<<- EOF ... EOF` is a heredoc, a way pass a multiline string (represented by the ellipsis) as `stdin` to one command, in this case `cat`. `<(command)` expands as a filename from which you can read the output of `command`. So `do_stuff` will behave as if you created a file with the JSON text (let's call it `input.json`) and called `notify @input.json`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<(...)` is a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). Bash creates a fifo in some directory and run the command inside `<(...)` and substitutes the expression with the fifo name. Process substitutions have (strange) lifetime rules, but they are usually valid till the end of command or line. For example:

```
$ cmd=<(echo 123); echo cmd=$cmd; cat $cmd
cmd=/dev/fd/63
123
```

`<<-EOF` is a [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents). If there is `-` in front of the *delimeter* then leading tabs on following lines including the line with *delimeter* are ignored. (Note: stackoverflow doesn't preserve tabs).

```
$ echo -e '
cat <<EOF
\tblabla
EOF
cat <<-EOF
\t\t\t\t\tblabla
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEOF
' > file.sh
$ bash ./file.sh
      blabla
blabla
```

`notify @<(...)` just substitutes the `<(...)` part inside for some `/dev/fd/<number>` and executes `notify @/dev/fd/<number>`. Probably the `@` is used for `notify` process to indicate it should read from file and the rest of the argument is the filename. Then the `cat` process that has tied output to `/dev/fd/<number>` fifo created with process substitution, the `cat` process receives the here document content `{ <more json data> }` on standard input. `cat` outputs standard input to output and then I guess `notify` reads the fifo and receives the characters.